# Files stealing from device or onedrive

Tags: security, files, onedrive

I have word files on onedrive and i use word for android to edit theme.
I want to know if the are secure. Can other applications acces themes ?
Can appliaction that have storage permession steall my files from the device ? Send theme to the web ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes... all the application needs is storage and internet permissions to do that, I've made several proof-of-concept apps to highlight this... Currently Androids first line of defence is On-Demand permission acceptance....

Comment: You can hypothetically clone an entire device partition also....

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hypothetically copy or clone files using some simple command like `cp` or `dd`

It's almost ridiculous... I use my Android for distribution of my personal copyrighted applications, I am honestly worried about the lack of care taken to protect data .. The Google Play Protect feature seems to illegally sample my applications and copy the copyright protected package names...

I believe the only thing you can do is to include a copyright statement in each file, this will mean that any copying will result in a breach of the copyright act...

The law is the only thing stopping people from doing this, however it is touch and go ( You accept the permission, therefore you give them the right )

It's all a bit strange with Android, because they aren't the owners of Java & Linux, they use Open Source software to build android, so therefore Android "Has" to be an open sourced project...

When it comes to advanced data miners ... They've got everything... Facebook, EBay, Google, etc... All send your data to the Axiom network ( Data Mining Center )   and therefore your Purchases, Online search history, SD card data, contacts, social behaviors etc... are all available to anyone willing to pay for it....

These days, nobody has privacy... It's all part of the Data mining and protection.

You are more likely to have protection by including your copyright statement, it's as simple as ...

> Copyright © "Your identity" 2019. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: ok. that's terrifying.